# Make a whole div clickable in order to launch a _blank document

Tags: javascript

How can I write the _blank statement in this location.href call?

```
  <div onclick="location.href='http://www.test.com';" style="display:block; height:40px; width:100px; cursor:pointer;"></div>
```

Please note: I need to keep the div and treat it as a href container. 
When someone clicks it should open a new browser window, not a popup box.

Comment: Howcome you're using a <div> instead of an <a> tag?

Comment: I need to keep the div and treat it as a href block. When someone clicks it should open a new browser window, not a popup box.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
<div onclick="window.open('http://www.test.com','new_window');" style="display:block; height:40px; width:100px; cursor:pointer;">test</div>
```

Comment: This solution worked out. Is there a way to make it fail proof in IE?

Comment: I was able to make it fail proof in IE by installing Firefox using IE.  ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Use [window.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open).

Answer (score 2):

or using jquery:

```
$(this).click(function(){

$(this).open(
{
 width: 400,
 height: 250,
 scrollbars: false
});
```

});

Answer (score 1):

use an `<a>` instead of a `<div>`

```
<a href="http://www.example.com" target="_blank" style="display:block; width:100px; height:40px;">CONTENT</a>
```